# Drag to right and delete

Tags: listview, flutter

I have a widget `ListView.builder` in Widget of `Card`. How can I drag to right the `ListTile` widget and delete that product from the List? The same of this image...

[image]

Comment: Check out this:https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/gestures/dismissible

Comment: @VirenVVarasadiya why don't you post an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Dismissible](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/gestures/dismissible) Widget to achieve it.

Following code may help you more to understand it.

```
final items = List<String>.generate(20, (i) => "Item ${i + 1}");

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Dismissable demo"),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: items.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          final item = items[index];
          return Dismissible(
              key: Key(item),
              onDismissed: (direction) {
                setState(() {
                  items.removeAt(index);
                });
                Scaffold.of(context)
                    .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("$item dismissed")));
              },
              background: Container(
                color: Colors.red,
                child: Icon(Icons.delete),
              ),
              child: Card(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                child: Text("$item"),
              ));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```